# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(3n)! \, e^n}{(2n)!\,n^n\,8^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(3n)! \, e^n}{(2n)!\,n^n\,8^n}$$

I tried by simplifying $n!$ divided by $n! = 1$? What should I do next? I get then $3!e^n / 2!n^n8^n$

Comment: I'm afraid $(3n)!/n!$ is NOT $3!$.

Comment: Note: $(3n)! \neq 3!n!$

Comment: My ellipsoids says 0

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**
$$
\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}
  = \left(\frac{e}{8n}\right)^n \prod_{k=1}^n (2n+k)
  = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2n+k}{8n/e}
  = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{e}{4} + \frac{ke}{8n}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Method:**

Obviously, $$0\le\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}$$

Also, observe $$\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}=\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!}\cdot(\frac{e}{8n})^n\le\frac{(3n)^n}{n^n}\cdot(\frac{e}{8n})^n=(\frac{3e}{8n})^n$$

So
$$0\le\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}\le(\frac{3e}{8n})^n$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{3e}{8n})^n$$
$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}\le0$$

So by Squeeze Theorem,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n)! e^n}{(2n)! n^n 8^n}=0$$